# Style not supporting EventSetter xaml windows app

Tags: windows, xaml, microsoft-metro

im trying to do a simple calculator program for windows 8, metro app, but when i need to do a style for eventhandling(and others stuff) i get "EventSetter is not supported in a windows app proyect"

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="my_button">
            <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="Button_Click_1"/>
</Style>
```

is there any other way i can do eventhandling in a style for metro apps?

Answer (score 0):

In general you can't attach events in a `Style` but for the specific example of `Button.Click` you can use a normal Setter to set a `Command` instead. If you use an MVVM style `ICommand` implementation (`RelayCommand`, `DelegateCommand`, etc) you can bind to an `ICommand` instance exposed from one of your classes:

```
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="my_button">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=MyClickCommand}"/>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Except that bindings are not supported on style setters either... :) No, in that case you need an attached behavior! :)